# How to create the constructor in haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor, functional-programming

Question : Define a new Rating type with the constructors One, Two, .. Five. It should derive Ord, Eq and Enum behaviors
Make the new type an instance of Show, giving the displays as the appropriate number
of stars (i.e., "*", "**" and so on)
My attempt :

```
import System.IO

data Rating = One String String String

getting :: Rating -> String

main = do
    getting(One _ _ p) = "*" * "*"
    let result = putStrLn (show ())
```

error:

```
$ghc -O2 --make *.hs -o main -threaded -rtsopts
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:17:20: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: I'm getting error saying"parse error on input data"

Comment: Please share the attempt you have made.

Comment: Can you please write the code for the question

Comment: I'm trying to implement but it's not working

Comment: [edit] the question and share your *current* attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Rating` type is supposed to have five data constructors from `One` to `Five`, so:

```
data Rating = One | Two | Three | Four | Five
```

we can then make `Rating` an instance of `Eq` and `Ord`. Since two `Rating`s are supposed to be equal only if we use the same data constructor, and a `Rating` is considered to be smaller than another `Rating` if the data constructor of the first `Rating` appears in the data definition before the second `Rating`, we can let Haskell derive the instances with:

```
data Rating = One | Two | Three | Four | Five deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

now the only thing left is the instance for `Show`, we have to write a custom implementation here, since it should show a number of asterisks (`*`), we thus can define the instance with:

```
instance Show Rating where
    show One = "*"
    show Two = …
    show Three = …
    show Four = …
    show Five = …
```

I leave implementing the `…`s as an exercise.